# download multiple files types

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file, download

I am using jsp servlet to upload and download files.

I want to download many types of files, so I choose to download them as zip files in order not to fall in defining each type of attachment in the response, when I make upload all of files uploaded correctly, when I make download for txt and docx files they are downloaded correctly too, but when I download pdf or image files, they are not downloaded correctly, since I put them in the same folder!

Comment: Huh? What is the question? What is your context? Downloading from what? Using what?

Comment: .. Java? downloading from the island?

Comment: No downloading using servlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *when I make download for txt and docx files they are downloaded correctly too, but when I download pdf or image files, they are not downloaded correctly*

Fact: `.txt` and `.docx` (XML!) files are **text** based while PDF and images are **binary** based.

So, it sounds much like that you read/write files using `Reader`/`Writer` instead of `InputStream`/`OutputStream`.

Fix the code accordingly. Never use `Reader`/`Writer` as long as you're not interested in the actual file content on a character basis. It will totally corrupt binary files. You can find a basic example of a download servlet [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html).

Comment: The example in the blog works very well if I store every thing about the file, it's name,  length and contentType, so I can get every thing in one statment <code> File file = fileDAO.find(fileId);</code>
but in a case i don't know any thing rather than the path, I can't know the type of attachment, so i download all files as zip .

Comment: It was just a basic example, man :) You're free to edit the code to your needs. You can use `ServletContext#getMimeType()` to get the content type by file extension as in 1st servlet example. The 2nd servlet example using `fileDAO` assumes that you've stored the whole file in DB instead of on disk. You've however the file already on disk. The content length can be obtained by `File#length()`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244521 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000587