# I would like receive vide/mp4 mime-type after passing filename xxx.mp4 in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mime-types, content-type

Is there any API in Java that can return the mime-type or content-Type as video/mp4 if I pass it .mp4 extension or complete filename?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [java.nio.file.Files#ProbeFileContent(path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29) which will by default use a extension-detector unless you have havnt registered any other [java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html):s

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Throwable {
        Path path = Paths.get("c:/test.mp4");
        String contentType = Files.probeContentType(path);

        System.out.println(contentType);
    }
}
```

will output:

```
video/mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently released my [SimpleMagic](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplemagic/) package which implements the same functionality as the Unix file(1) command.  It uses either internal config files or can read `/etc/magic`, `/usr/share/file/magic`, or other magic(5) files and determine file content from `File`, `InputStream`, or `byte[]`.  It actually uses the content bytes of the file instead of just the name however.

Location of the [github sources](https://github.com/j256/simplemagic), javadocs, and some documentation are available from the [home page](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplemagic/).

Comment: I have the impression that the question is poorly formulated and that the OP is essentially asking exactly the same question as already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244432/how-should-response-content-type-for-documents-be-specified-in-order-to-work-con/2244521#2244521 In other words, his concrete problem is that he got `null` while using `ServletContext#getMimeType()` on a `.mp4` file.

Comment: Maybe @BalusC.  Thought my mimetype library might help somehow.  Thanks.